# Example that a union of topologies can be a topology

Tags: general-topology

I have to show that the union of two topologies on a set may or may not be a topology on the set. I had no problem finding a counterexample, but I want to make sure that my other example is okay (i.e. showing that the union may be another topology).

I let $X$ be any nonempty set and then used the indiscrete and discrete topologies such that $\mathcal{T}_{1}=\{\varnothing, X\}$ and $\mathcal{T}_{2}=2^{X}$. Then $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{T}_{1}\cup\mathcal{T}_{2}=2^{X}$ so that $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology.

Is this correct? Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: You are correct, but $\mathcal{T}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{T}_2$.  To super-impress your instructor, find an example where one doesn't trivially gobble up the other.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: You can come up with a related example without the containment property by taking $X\sqcup X$, the disjoint union of two copies of $X$.

Comment: For a simple concrete example where $\mathcal T_1$ and $\mathcal T_2$ are not nested, consider $X = \{a,b\}$, and let $\mathcal T_1 = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, X\}$ and $\mathcal T_2 = \{\emptyset, \{b\}, X\}$.